# What is the output if we compare two integers which are converted to string format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is `'2' > '10'`? What is the output if we compare two integers which are converted to string format?

I am getting true but it's false, right?

[image]

Comment: Strings are compared *lexicographically*, character by character; `'1' < '2'` so `'10' < '2'`.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing strings, you compare them lexicographically. The character `2` comes after the character `1`, so the result is `True`. The fact that these two strings could be converted to integers is inconsequential.

Comment: This doesn't need answering *again*, please VTC as duplicate.

Comment: I got it .Thanks